Norton 360 has suddenly started to flag my Andriod App as "Malware", any way to see why?
Since last week Norton 360 and AVG/Avast has started to flag my app as Malware for some reason, no updates has been done on the app for several weeks.
Google Play Protect, Windows Defender, BitDefender has no objections on the app.
The app is created by pure JavaScript and HTML and packaged by the online site webintohtml.com
Is there any way to see WHY the app suddenly has been marked as Malware by Norton 360 (and AVG/Avast)? There is no way to get thru with Nortons support, its only nonsense answers from them
It seems strange that only these are marking it as Malware, especially since its a so simple web application.

Possibly a false positive, but since you've included no code, it's difficult to say, though, I'd be hesitant in using a 3rd party 'packager' since you don't really know how your app is packaged.   That said,  there's really little anyone here can do aside for finding a different way of packaging your app.

I was hoping that there was a way to see any information about why Norton 360 flags it as unsafe/malware

Probably because it has a similar signature to a piece of malware in its signature database.  That's my guess and you're going to have to send your app to Norton for their testing... (I don't deal with Norton, so I wouldn't know.)  Either way,  your question is pretty much off topic unless you feel it's a piece of code in your app that's triggering this.
